# admob is in the middle in drawer layout

Tags: android, admob

I am trying to show admob in drawer layout but it is always in the middle of the screen and overlays the content instead of at the bottom.

this is how it looks like:

[image]

and this is my layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_wallpaper_full"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_wallpaper_full"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_wallpaper_full_drawer" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit_id_wallpaper_full_activity">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the navigation drawer to obscure the ad (when the drawer is open), then you should move the `<AdView>` tag inside the `<include>`-ed layout (i.e. put it inside the `app_bar_wallpaper_full.xml` layout file).

The right way to position the ad at the bottom of the screen will depend on what kind of layout you're using in `app_bar_wallpaper_full.xml`.

If you want the ad to always be fully visible, and to have the navigation drawer stop before it covers up the ad, then you need to put both the `DrawerLayout` and the `AdView` inside a `LinearLayout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_wallpaper_full"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_wallpaper_full"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_wallpaper_full_drawer"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit_id_wallpaper_full_activity"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"/>

</LinearLayout>
```